# jsctypes finalizer cross domain issue

Tags: firefox-addon, cross-domain, jsctypes

I've successfully used jsctypes in the past but the latest version of firefox (32) has started to  give me an odd error message

here is what used to work-

javascript content sends a message to a javascript extension in chrome (the extension uses ctypes to call a special device allocator. it then returns a cdata.finalizer to the content 
later when the content is garbage collected the finaizer gets called to release the special device allocation

while this used to work fine, I'm now getting an exception ctypes.CDataFinalizer
 Not allowed to define cross-origin object as property on [Object] or [Array] XrayWrapper

searching on Google did not seem to find anything related.

on the extension I have this code( the func... things are access methods for c code)

Any suggestions?

```
self.addEventListener("allocArray", function (event) {
     var info = event.detail.info;
     try {
         var cBytes = ctypes.int32_t(info.bytes);
         var cArrayId = ctypes.uint32_t(0);
         var err = funcAllocArray(cBytes,  cArrayId.address());
         if(err !== 0) {
              info.rtnCode = err;
              info.arrayId = -1;
              info.error = "Error: " + (err === 2)? "out of memory": "allocation failed";
          } else {
               info.rtnCode = 0;
               info.arrayId = ctypes.CDataFinalizer(cArrayId.value, funcReleaseArray);
          }
     }
     catch(exception) {
         info.rtnCode = -1;
         info.arrayId = -1;
         info.error = report(exception);
      }
  }, true, true);
```

Comment: if you want attention to your jsctypes topics you have to give it the firefox-addon tag, otherwise no one will ever see it. did you figure this one out?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this :)

Comment: i did actually figure this out, i had to add event = XPCNati eWrapper.unwrap(event) to the code as of firefox 30 a content object gets wrapped when it inters a chrome extension and we cannot store native objects live a cdatafinalizer into the obect

Comment: very interesting. what do you mean by chrome extension? you mean firefox privelgaed code? or google chrome browser?